# How to create an escrow account without runtime upgrade

Tags: frame, account, pallet-treasury

I'd like to create an account that is only usable through the root origin like the treasury account. It should be possible to transfer funds to it, but sending from it should only be possible through the logic of the pallet that I'm developing.

I could just instanciate the treasury pallet, but I would like to dynamically create them on user request.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are willing to use Root origin then you can use any account. Assuming you are using 32 byte account IDs, you can just hash something to get an otherwise inaccessible account. Then do a Root dispatch of `balances.force_transfer`.

I actually did this before on Kusama: https://kusama.polkassembly.io/motion/394

Namely:

```
hash(“xcm_exploit_karura_extrinsic_735603-2”) = 0x407d09daacfb6586a4fa1b3083e5c2002275d9ebbd67f2c0a2c6f2701ec43376
```

Which as a 32-byte `AccountId` = `E2sj6XZ4GxzMon1QNycjrQaQsKRaY3zb2jRKREiPRmX1sfQ`